# Calculating 3D posing using two Wiimotes with 90 degrees separation

Tags: 3d, camera, position, angle

I'd like to mount two wii remotes on a frame, mounted 90 degrees relative to each other, in hope of finding the x,y,z position of a given pixel in 3D space.

I'm not concerned about getting the data from the wiimotes, that's easy enough. What I'm struggling to understand is the calculations behind it.

I've spent some time researching (and experimenting), and from what I understand, it's not possible to use simple Cartesian geometry to obtain the real 3D position of a point.

Most of the questions I've seen on here and other websites are concerned with two cameras mounted at a set distance apart (stereoscopy). My needs differ, because I need to *see behind* points.

From what I've gathered so far, I need to obtain a *camera matrix* to relate the x,y co-ordinates to 3D position. But that's as much as I get... And I don't really get that.

Providing I can obtain the x,y position of a given pixel on 2 cameras with 90 degree separation. How do I obtain the x,y,z position?

The crap diagram below explains the situation:

[image]

Note: The cameras are angled, such that (0,0) responds to the middle of the floor.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the point from one camera, that not really a point, but a vector that runs from camera through the object to the floor or wall.

So I would start from trying to calculate this vector.

Then you would add the vector info from the other camera and compare them to find where they meet.